ValueError: The layer sequential has never been called and thus has no defined input. on transfer learning
I am working on network_based transfer learning with iris dataset.
it shows a error：
ValueError: The layer sequential has never been called and thus has no defined input.

on the line
feature_extractor = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=model.get_layer(index=1).output)

here is the full code
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# load Iris dataset
iris = load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Standarize dataset
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)

# network for original task
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(4,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')  # output layer, 3 classes
])

# compile model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# train model
history = model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.1, verbose=0)

# plot training and validation loss
plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='Validation Loss')
plt.title('Training and Validation Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# plot training and validation accuracy
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'], label='Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'], label='Validation Accuracy')
plt.title('Training and Validation Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# THE ERROR IS ON THIS LINE
feature_extractor = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=model.get_layer(index=1).output)

# freeze the weight of extractor
feature_extractor.trainable = False

# creat new classification model for objective task
new_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    feature_extractor,
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')  # output layer, 3 classes
])

# compile new model
new_model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

# train new model
history_new = new_model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.1, verbose=0)

# plot training and validation loss
plt.plot(history_new.history['loss'], label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(history_new.history['val_loss'], label='Validation Loss')
plt.title('New Model Training and Validation Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# plot training and validation accuracy
plt.plot(history_new.history['accuracy'], label='Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(history_new.history['val_accuracy'], label='Validation Accuracy')
plt.title('New Model Training and Validation Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# evaluate the new model
test_loss, test_acc = new_model.evaluate(X_test_scaled, y_test, verbose=2)
print('\nTest accuracy:', test_acc)

I tried to ask Github Copilot. And it ask me to add
model.predict(X_train_scaled[0:1])

in front of the line shows error. But it didn't work
What am I doing wrong?

The sequential model dynamically creates an input layer, but its shape isn't defined until the model  is called. so when you try to access model.input, it doesn't know about the input shape and throws an error. So to access the input,  you should explicitly refer to the input of the first layer by using model.get_layer(index=0).input or else you can use functional model instead of sequential model. Please refer this gist.
